# Unwrapping optional properties from an optional array of objects

Tags: swift

I'm currently working with an SDK where methods return an optional array of objects with optional properties.  Only the array itself is optional, it will either be nil or always contain non-optionals.  I'm struggling to find a cleaner way to unwrap optional properties for each non-optional in the array:

```
class Person {
    var id: String?
}

func someOptionalArrayOfPeople() -> [Person]? {
    // returns either nil or some array of Person objects
}

let people = someOptionalArrayOfPeople()

if let unwrappedPeople = people {

    // 1
    for person in unwrappedPeople {
        if let id = person.id {
            print(id) // too many nested statements
        }
    }

    // 2
    for person in unwrappedPeople where person.id != nil {
        print(person.id!) // stil force unwrapping
    }
}
```

For option 1, I'm not thrilled about unwrapping the initial optional array, and I feel that there should be a way to skip the unwrapping of the `id`.  Option 2 attempts to do that with a `where` clause, but the compiler isn't smart enough to determine that `person.id` is non-`nil` even if we explicitly check that `id != nil`.

What are my "Swifty" options for unwrapping optional properties on an optional array of objects?  I am using Swift 2.2 with Xcode 7.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options, but in any case you can use

```
public func flatMap<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> [T]
```

which returns an array containing the non-nil results of applying the
transformation to all sequence elements.

For example

```
if let unwrappedPeople = people {
    for id in unwrappedPeople.flatMap({ $0.id }) {
        print(id)
    }
}
```

to iterate over the non-nil ids, or

```
if let unwrappedPeople = people {
    let ids = unwrappedPeople.flatMap { $0.id }
    print(ids)
}
```

to get the non-nil ids as an array.

To get rid of the outer unwrapping/optional binding, you can use
*optional chaining*:

```
people?.flatMap({ $0.id }).forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

If `people` is `nil`, then `flatMap()` is not applied. Otherwise
it returns an array of the non-nil ids, which are enumerated with
`forEach()`.

I think that all these methods (as well as your first method) are "Swifty",
you have to decide how compact your code should be.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Martin!  Will give these a shot and follow up if I have any other questions.

Comment: Hey Martin, could I flatten the array of people based on `id` so that I could have an array of `Person` objects with a non-nil `id`?  Sort of like your second answer, but where I `$0` is a reference to the person, not the `id`.  Thanks.

Comment: Would something like `people?.filter({ $0.id != nil})` work?

Comment: @JAL: Sure. But note that the result is an (optional) array of `Person`, so you still have to unwrap the ids (even if you know that they are not nil).

Comment: Yep, that's another downer.  Wish I could strangle the devs who architected this API.  A property such as `id` which should be on every object should not be an optional.  But that's another issue.  Thanks Martin, wish I could upvote you twice.